# how to convert the dictionary with the list item to the pandas.Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

```
data_dict = {'A': [1,3,3], 'B': [2,3,3]}
```

convert to

```
A 1  
A 3  
A 3  
B 2  
B 3  
B 3
```

I tried to loop, but it is not simple enough. Is there any more simple method?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data_dict = {'A': [1,3,3], 'B': [2,3,3]}
s = pd.Series(data_dict).explode()
print(s)
```

```
A    1
A    3
A    3
B    2
B    3
B    3
dtype: object
```